# How to move some value in a column to different column on the same row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to solve this problem but I couldn't think of the logic, I wanted to move a value that has 'NAM' word in column B and replace it in column A that has 'GMO' word. Here's the Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

dataa = {'A':['NAM 1','NAM 2','NAM 3','GMO 12','NAM 5','GMO 2','NAM 7','NAM 8','GMO 32','GMO 22','NAM 11','NAM 12'],
         'B':['OBJ Y','OBJ N','OBJ Y','NAM 4','OBJ N','NAM 6','OBJ Y','OBJ Y','NAM 9','NAM 10','OBJ Y','OBJ N']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(dataa)
df

    A         B
0   NAM 1   OBJ Y
1   NAM 2   OBJ N
2   NAM 3   OBJ Y
3   GMO 12  NAM 4
4   NAM 5   OBJ N
5   GMO 2   NAM 6
6   NAM 7   OBJ Y
7   NAM 8   OBJ Y
8   GMO 32  NAM 9
9   GMO 22  NAM 10
10  NAM 11  OBJ Y
11  NAM 12  OBJ N
```

The output should be like this:

```
A       B
0   NAM 1   OBJ Y
1   NAM 2   OBJ N
2   NAM 3   OBJ Y
3   NAM 12  NAM 4
4   NAM 5   OBJ N
5   NAM 2   NAM 6
6   NAM 7   OBJ Y
7   NAM 8   OBJ Y
8   NAM 32  NAM 9
9   NAM 22  NAM 10
10  NAM 11  OBJ Y
11  NAM 12  OBJ N
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you chose to change the accepted answer, but know that the iterrows method is much less efficient. You won't benefit from C-speed vectorization brought by `where` and `str.startswith` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do an iteration through each row of the data frame:

```
for row, value in df.iterrows():
    if re.match('NAM\s', value[1]):
        df.iloc[row, 0] = df.iloc[row, 0].replace('GMO', 'NAM')
    else:
        pass

print(df)


    A       B
0   NAM 1   OBJ Y
1   NAM 2   OBJ N
2   NAM 3   OBJ Y
3   NAM 12  NAM 4
4   NAM 5   OBJ N
5   NAM 2   NAM 6
6   NAM 7   OBJ Y
7   NAM 8   OBJ Y
8   NAM 32  NAM 9
9   NAM 22  NAM 10
10  NAM 11  OBJ Y
11  NAM 12  OBJ N
```

The logic: If 'NAM' is detected in column B of that row, then access column A and replace 'GMO' with 'NAM', else do nothing. Note that the code above makes use of Python's regex package, so do run `import re` before executing the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].where(~df['A'].str.startswith('GMO'), df['B'])
```